# Scroll a specific scrollbar out of available ones to the item which is not visible on launch by default

Tags: ui-automation, pywinauto

I am trying to reach to a page in my GUI using pywinauto and scroll it to a spefic page(lets this spefic page is something which has a unique title and is somehwere where we must scroll it to the bottom) and add some text in it.

I am unable to get that scrollbar of pages list to scroll, maybe because its not the only scrollbar present in the application?
attaching my target area where i want to scroll as well.
Any help is very much appreciated .
[image: target area]

Here's what I think.

i didn't use
`pywinauto.mouse.move() pywinauto.mouse.scroll()`
as it takes arguments as cooordinates. but the coordinates of this scrollbar can change and is not under my control. and as i also mentioened there are more scrollbars present.
same goes with `.wheel_mouse_input()`

Somewhere in a post i saw the .ensure_visible() can be used to scroll to the item which is not visible but it didn't work as when i used it give gave me an ElementNotFoundError.
Please let me know if you got anything, Thanks!

pywinauto - 0.6.8
python - 3.11
IDE - visual studio code
backend used - "uia"

Comment: Maybe this comment would be helpful: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/941#issuecomment-640023029